# Updating multiple records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a client table in SQL Server where I need to change the expiry date of 450 different clients.

The new expiry date should be the same for all 450 clients.

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE Clients
SET SmartCardExpiry = 20200123
WHERE ClientId IN (*ClientID's for all 450 clients separated by a comma*)
```

Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: You can also do `... WHERE ClientId IN (select ClientID from ...)`.

Comment: As you are trying to pass the comma separated values in where condition for this you need to implement the logic to separate that comma separated values. You can use string_split() function. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/

Comment: also you can add the client id In a temp table and  later on use that to select the client ids.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your question body you are missing the single quote while passing values of date. So, it would be.

```
UPDATE Clients
SET SmartCardExpiry = '20200123'
```

To pass values in where condition which as separated by comma you can use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/) function.

```
WHERE ClientId IN (SELECT 
    value  
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT('1, 2, 5', ','))
```

Although [String_Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not available in lower version of SQL Server hence you might need to write custom query for separate and pass values in where condition.